# Error while importing ArrayType in Glue job

Tags: aws-glue

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import ArrayType
```

For this I am getting error in Glue job

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ArrayType' from 'pyspark.sql.functions' (/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py)
```

Using following version of glue

[image]

On using next Glue version Glue 4.0 with spark 3.3 getting another error

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import ArrayType 
from pyspark.sql.functions import StringType

class JobBase(object):
    
    #all udf has to be initialised as first step 
    def __init__(self):
        print("Inside the constructor of Class phases ")


        self.winner_org_calculation_udf=udf(JobBase.winner_org_calculation, ArrayType(StringType()))
```

```
TypeError: ArrayType.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'elementType'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this , I used below mentioned imports  and it resolved my problem

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
```